# No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found Core 3.1

Tags: windows, authentication, .net-core

I have a WEB API application written in C# with .NET Core 3.1 that uses Windows Authentication.  It builds and runs fine locally, but fails when it is deployed.  The error is:

> No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme

The error also tells me that I should define it in startup.cs in services.AddAuthenication.  This is the line from my startup.cs:

services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

I tried adding the nuget for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration but that made no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your production enviroment? Did you deploy to IIS? If so and you rely on IIS to authenticate the requests, you must disable anonymous access on IIS level